# PHP DOMDocument - trouble accessing list index

Tags: php, domdocument

I am writing some code for an IRC bot written in php and running on the linux cli. I'm having a little trouble with my code to retrieve a websites title tag and display it using DOMDocument NodeList. Basically, on websites with two or more  tags (and you would be surprised how many there actually are...) I want to process for only the first title tag. As you can see from the code below (which is working fine for processing one, or more tags) there is a foreach block where it iterates through each title tag.

```
public function onReceivedData($data) {

    // loop through each message token
    foreach ($data["message"] as $token) {


    // if the token starts with www, add http file handle
    if (strcmp(substr($token, 0, 4), "www.") == 0) {

        $token = "http://" . $token;

    }

    // validate token as a URL
    if (filter_var($token, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {

    // create timeout stream context
    $theContext['http']['timeout'] = 3;
    $context = stream_context_create($theContext);
    // get contents of url
    if ($file = file_get_contents($token, false, $context)) {

        // instantiate a new DOMDocument object
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        // load the html into the DOMDocument obj
        @$dom->loadHTML($file);
        // retrieve the title from the DOM node
        // if assignment is valid then...
        if ($title = $dom->getElementsByTagName("title")) {
             // send a message to the channel

             foreach ($title as $theTitle) {

                $this->privmsg($data["target"], $theTitle->nodeValue);

             }

        }

 } else {

        // notify of failure
        $this->privmsg($data["target"], "Site could not be reached");

 }

 }

 }

 }
```

What I'd prefer, is to somehow limit it to only processing the first title tag. I'm aware that I can just wrap an if statement around it with a variable so it only echos one time, but I'm more looking at using a "for" statement to process a single iteration. However, when I do this, I can't access the title attribute with $title->nodeValue; it says it's undefined, and only when i use the foreach $title as $theTitle can I access the values. I've tried $title[0]->nodeValue and $title->nodeValue(0) to retrieve the first title from the list, but unfortunately to no avail. A bit stumped and a quick google didn't turn up a lot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers, and I'll  keep looking too.

Comment: Thanks guys I stumbled upon the answer I needed as soon as I posted :D Appreciate the replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$title->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Can't upvote as I'm a new user

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with **XPath**:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($file);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$title = $xpath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: XPath is so underrated. If you are going to be working with XML, you absolutely HAVE GOT to know XPath.

Comment: That's why I love XPath! It's a brilliant device to parse websites.

Comment: Thanks guys I stumbled upon the answer I needed as soon as I posted :D Appreciate the replies

Comment: And what was the answer? Accept the one you found most useful otherwise.

Comment: Whilst XPath is an interesting enlightenment, and both answers provided the syntax I required, I had to tick the other one. Cheers for your help anyway!